# Error in PHP but solved while i cut the script then paste again with same script

Tags: php, phalcon

i have a problem while develop PHP application using Phalcon Micro. My story are, i create a specific API then run it, but result is error. Then i cut the script, execute it, error not shown. So, i paste again that script, then... script run normaly as i wish.

What happend with my PHP scripts? I tried find error in /var/log/php/error.log, but nothing.

Here is my PHP version:

```
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Mar 30 2018 10:43:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.16,
```

Comment: Occasionally an editor will have a hiccup and introduce a minor corruption. It has happened to me a few time over the years. The Cut and Paste for some reason almost always corrects the corruption

Comment: so, cut and paste method are not magic? oh god... it's first time i have an error like this.